# Not able to get expected output for SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getCreateObjectOptions API with Object Filter.

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to check weather a given "operatingSystemReferenceCode" is valid or not using below Softlayer API.
were I am mentioning the  operatingSystemReferenceCode in Object Filter.
Even if I pass an invalid "operatingSystemReferenceCode" I will get success response.
I tried many way to build objectFilter, but could'nt get the expected out put.
Can any one help me to build a proper objectFilter.

API :

https://:@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getCreateObjectOptions?objectFilter={"virtualGuests":{"CreateObjectOptions":{"operatingSystems":{"template":{"operatingSystemReferenceCode":{"operation":"CWWSDCSENTOS_7_64_34542"}}}}}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::getCreateObjectOptions method is an special one, you cannot apply any objectFilter or object mask, you can see that even in documentation:

https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getCreateObjectOptions/

bellow optional headers you should be able to see objectFilter like in this method

https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualGuests/

but the optional headers for getCreateObjectOptions is empty

Comment: is there any other API to check weather given "operatingSystemReferenceCode" is valid or not before creating an Virtual Server.

Comment: you could user the https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/generateOrderTemplate/ method in order to validate if all the configured data to create the VSI are correct